# createChooser not displaying title

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-listview, android-adapter

In Customadapter.java file,I have written this part of code below.

In that when I click on any listview item,sharing window opens but I cannot see the title "Share Using" mentioned in createChooser.Please help me.

CustomAdapter.java

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom,null);
        TextView tv1=v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        final TextView tv2=v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tv3=v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv1.setText(arrayList.get(position).getId()+"");
        tv2.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
        tv3.setText(arrayList.get(position).getAddress());


        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent ();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, tv2.getText().toString());
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                context.startActivity(
                        Intent.createChooser(
                                intent,
                                "Share using"
                        )
                );
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Whether the title appears will depend on OS version and possibly device manufacturer.

Comment: so how to know which will display and which will not?

Comment: In general, you don't. You offer the title, and whether it is shown will depend on the circumstances.

Comment: follow this link - https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sharing-Content-with-Intents

Comment: where it is mentioned why it is not displayinh?

Comment: @CommonsWare can you please tell me how to display it anyhow?

Comment: @CommonsWare How to report this to Google?Even google documentation doesnt say that it depends on device.Its difficult to learn Android like this.

Comment: "How to report this to Google?" -- Google is well aware of the fact that device manufacturers can change Android. This has been a feature of the Android ecosystem from the beginning, over a decade ago. So long as the modified Android passes compatibility tests, Google allows such changes. Google themselves do not necessarily honor every `Intent` extra from Android 1.0 in Android 11.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentations for `Intent.createChooser(...)`:

> @param title Optional **title** that **will be displayed** in the chooser,
> **only when the target action is not ACTION_SEND or ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE**.

In your code, you have:

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

That's why you won't see any title.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236947/android-app-adding-a-share-button-to-share-the-app-on-social-networks

Comment: If you go through above link,even if it is intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND),we can still see the title.

Comment: Alright, tested it locally, the title does show up even for `ACTION_SEND`, guess I should not trust android documentations that much :/ the docs were here btw: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence)
Does the title show up if you change the action to sth else?

Comment: Hey,how you manged to show the tite.Please explain.

Comment: I copied your exact code, and the title was showing. I did not change anything. I run the code on Samsung Galaxy S9. As @CommonsWare commented on your question, this is probably hardware dependent, and I don't see a way to manipulate it.

Comment: I discovered that title is displayed on emulator with API 25