# How to share images and text using recyclerview to other apps Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, share

## this is my adapter script code

```
package com.satset.satsetapps

import android.content.ContentResolver
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.net.Uri
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions


class CardViewHeroAdapter internal constructor(
    private val listHero: ArrayList<Hero>,
    private val contentResolver: ContentResolver?,
    private val resources: Resources?
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewHeroAdapter.CardViewViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewViewHolder {
        val view: View =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_cardview_hero, parent, false)
        return CardViewViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardViewViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val hero = listHero[position]

        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
            .load(hero.photo)
            .apply(RequestOptions().override(200, 200))
            .into(holder.imgPhoto)

        holder.tvName.text = hero.name
        holder.tvDetail.text = hero.detail

        holder.btnFavorite.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(
                holder.itemView.context,
                "Favorite " + listHero[holder.adapterPosition].name,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

        holder.btnShare.setOnClickListener {
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, hero.photo);
            val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(contentResolver, bitmap, "Title", null)
            val uri = Uri.parse(path)
            val shareIntent = Intent()
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, hero.name)
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, hero.detail)
            shareIntent.type = "image/*"
            holder.itemView.context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Via..."))
            }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(
                holder.itemView.context,
                "Kamu memilih " + listHero[holder.adapterPosition].name,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }
    
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listHero.size
    }

    inner class CardViewViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var imgPhoto: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_item_photo)
        var tvName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name)
        var tvDetail: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_detail)
        var btnFavorite: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_set_favorite)
        var btnShare: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_set_share)
    }
}
```

## Paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path
        name="myimages"
        path="images/" />

    <cache-path
        name="shared_images"
        path="MyImagesShare/" />

    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />

    <external-files-path
        name="images"
        path="Pictures" />

</paths>
```

## Manifest

```
<provider
android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="com.satset.satsetapps.fileprovider"
android:grantUriPermissions="true"
android:exported="false">

<meta-data
android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

## i'm still learning kotlin so i still don't understand how to make it.

the purpose of learning I want to be able to click share the following image with text to various applications such as whatsapp

How many days have I searched the website and youtube but there is no meeting point

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a "share" button to share the app on social networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236947/adding-a-share-button-to-share-the-app-on-social-networks)

Comment: yes share images and text to social networking apps

for the button is already provided

with the code the application is already running but when I click the share button immediately force close

Comment: yes share image and text to social networking apps

for the buttons that have been provided

If what is shared is only text, it's already running, but here I want to include a picture too